# Datastax driver Issue getting TransportException

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I'm using datastax driver version

```
<datastax.version>2.0.8</datastax.version>
```

and soon after my app initializes, I see TransportException error from datastax.
I've looked up online and found and a jira ticket opened on a similar issue from datastax but that doesn't provide enough information about the resolution.

```
2014-11-17 18:13:48.866/EST ERROR [Reconnection-0] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 1000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:13:49.871/EST ERROR [Reconnection-0] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 2000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:13:51.871/EST ERROR [Reconnection-1] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 4000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:13:55.874/EST ERROR [Reconnection-0] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 8000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:14:03.875/EST ERROR [Reconnection-1] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 16000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:14:19.876/EST ERROR [Reconnection-0] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 32000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:14:51.876/EST ERROR [Reconnection-1] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 64000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:15:55.877/EST ERROR [Reconnection-0] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 128000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:18:03.878/EST ERROR [Reconnection-1] [ControlConnection] [Control connection] Cannot connect to any host, scheduling retry in 256000 milliseconds
2014-11-17 18:18:09.355/EST ERROR [Cassandra Java Driver blocking tasks worker-1] [Session] Error creating pool to xx5001xxxs01/192.168.100.121:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [xx5001xxxs01/192.168.100.121:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:105)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:522)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:86)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$2.call(SessionManager.java:230)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$2.call(SessionManager.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: xx5001xxxs01/192.168.100.121:9042
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
        ... 3 more
2014-11-17 18:18:16.147/EST ERROR [Cassandra Java Driver blocking tasks worker-1] [Session] Error creating pool to xx5001xxxs03.xyzcompany.com/192.168.100.123:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [xx5001xxxs03.xyzcompany.com/192.168.100.123:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:105)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:522)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:86)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$2.call(SessionManager.java:230)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$2.call(SessionManager.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: xx5001xxxs03.xyzcompany.com/192.168.100.123:9042
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:599)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
        ... 3 more
```

Can someone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your nodes down a the time? Please share some more details on how you get to this error to help reproduce.

Comment: I see two potentially similar issues, have you looked at both? https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-535 and https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-466

Comment: No, there were no nodes that were brought down. I'm getting this error soon after the app initializes, and I'm able to work with the app later, but I just wanna make sure the database thread aren't stuck and go stale after some time.

Comment: Is your app executing a lot of concurrent requests at that time? Could you check the TCP connections at the OS level on the server? (something like `lsof -i TCP:9042` if you're on a linux box)